# What's with the Japanese SO's stats?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats

I took this screenshot just now, and [got these interesting stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#uncategorized-traffic) about the new [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/). I refreshed the page, went back, and nothing changed.

> [image: screenshot of Japanese stats]

And, here's what I find odd:

1. It clearly isn't almost 2014 years old. That's more likely when it was started.
2. How can there be 8.7 questions a day, while there are 0 visits a day? That's kind of impossible.

I'm hoping here that it's not just me.

*I know very limited Japanese, not even enough to hold a conversation with a toddler. I'm merely observing.*

Comment: The site doesn't appear at all for me in the list.

Comment: Try [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#uncategorized-traffic)

Comment: Nope. No site, and even weirder, it's not on Area 51. Weird!

Comment: There's no Japanese SO on the list!?

Comment: It's official now. jp.so is older than Jesus.

Comment: Okay. This is just weird. And AFAIK it does, given Stack Exchange's latest blog post.

Comment: Finally I can see the site in there. That's a very aggressive caching... and a very unique bug!

Comment: I think it could be something with the different date formats used there, and the programmers whose task were to fix that, are soon on christmas leave.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Japan has a very long and storied history. Little known is that during the [Yayoi era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayoi_period) the Japanese invented computers, the internet, and yes, even Stack Overflow, but unfortunately the database became corrupted sometime during the [Warring States era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuchi%E2%80%93Momoyama_period). That's why the stats seem wrong. What is certain, however, is that 8.7 questions/day over 2013 years makes Japanese Stack Overflow by far the biggest resource of programming questions on the internet.

Or alternatively, the numbers are a bit off because we didn't have an Area 51 proposal for this, and as a result it's being fixed.

I like the first explanation far more though.

Comment: Actually, 8.7 questions per day over 2013 years amounts to about 6.4M questions, which is 3/4 of the number of questions on English SO.

Comment: @Gilles Why must you spoil the fun? ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm with impinball here. I was on Cloud 9 thinking how much more awesome the Japanese site is than English due to its age, and then you shattered all my dreams.

Comment: Your next step should have been to point out that the q/day stat is for recent times (2 weeks IIRC) and find a good reason why ja.SO would have had more questions than en.SO after all. When someone nerds you out, don't whine, outnerd them!

Comment: 6-8 weeks until it will be fixed then?

Comment: Still waiting on this to be adjusted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 6-8 weeks. Or three. But who's counting?

Comment: @jmac eh, thanks for fixing! ;-)

Comment: Given that the first analogue computer was the [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism) in Hellas at ~100BC, this answer could introduce a new hypothesis.. I am only concerned about the invention of SO that you stated . . . :)

Answer (score 3):

This has been tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but the [site stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#uncategorized-traffic) still seem a little bit bugged out:

[image: screenshot of the stats, problems explained below]

Visits/day is still at 0.

Questions/day doesn't look right, unless 2/3 of the site's questions have been deleted. (Maybe they have been, since it's brand new.) The site *does* have [only 574 questions](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions). It is also just now beginning its 4th month, so let's count this as 3 months:

- 3 months × 30 days/month (conservatively) × 16 questions/day = **1440 questions.**

Comment: Should I untag it?

Comment: @impinball I don't know, that's a good question.

Comment: Especially given that I just saw the same thing on a phone?

Comment: @impinball I've asked here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246585/152515

Comment: @impinball Moot point; the tags shown in red, like (status-something), are moderator-only.

Comment: @Fundamental I thought it was only adding them that was moderator-only. I haven't tried removing them, but is that truly mod-only too?

Comment: Yes, it is -- I just tried it to confirm.

Comment: @Fundamental true enough; I just did the same. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that the questions/day are being measured since December 2nd when the private beta started (574/35 = 16.4 questions/day). While the site is technically 4 months old, a lot of that time it was being tested and isn't counted. The rest of the stats, save visits/day, seem right (visits/day may require time to update).

Comment: @jmac Isn't the questions/day calculated as ["per day on average over the last 2 weeks"](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/5887/23682)? The numbers seem to match up: [227 questions in the past 2 weeks](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2014-12-24..2015-01-06+is%3Aquestion) / 14 = 16.2 (on a side note, good thing the site is keeping up its pace)

Comment: @ento That makes sense too -- clearly I should have done my homework first. Thanks for the save!

Comment: @jmac Visits/day just kicked into gear sometime in the past hour or two. \o/ All is well now.