# Russian SE has a slightly longer and more storied history than Japanese SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats

In what I assume is a repeat of [What's with the Japanese SO's stats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245386/254929), the ["All Sites" page sorted by age in list view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest) shows that Rus.SE is 2014 years, 3 months old (click for full resolution):

[image: site age: 2014y3m]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are aware of this and will be deploying a fix with other changes to SE.COM in the near future.