# Site list shows wrong age of rus.se

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) says that [rus.stackexchange.com](http://rus.stackexchange.com) was opened 2014 years ago.

Can this be fixed please?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245386/whats-with-the-japanese-sos-stats

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to add this to the checklist of "stuff that breaks when we do other languages".

Comment: @jmac this will happen again in the next new Stack Overflow site - should we start new bug report, or ping you here?

Comment: @ShadowWizard theoretically, it shouldn't happen next time. But if it does, feel free to ping me here and/or start a new meta post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sorted now.

This is an issue we have with sites that didn't go through the Area51 process (which is rather rare, so we don't always remember all the knobs that need to be manually tweaked).